Why are my function keys acting like Character (A-E) keys
I'm running Ubuntu Studio 24.04 (Wayland).  Recently, I began troubleshooting my sound (which stopped working).  In the process of working on sound (alsa, pulseaudio, etc.), I somehow caused function keys F1-F5 to begin returning capital alpha characters (i.e., 'A' - 'E').  The rest of the function keys (F6-F12) appear to have their normal behavior.
I have sought answers to this problem on AskUbuntu, but found nothing related to my issue.  It's not obvious to me how analyzing/troubleshooting sound issues affected the Function Keys.
How do I restore behavior for F1 - F5 keys?
